# using getWindowManager() inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to use `getWindowManager()` inside `BroadcastReceiver` and I get this error:

"The method `getWindowManager()` is undefined for the type `MyReceiver`"

I just need to get `display.getWidth()` and `display.getHeight()`

Any hints? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`getWindowManager()` is a method on `Activity`. You cannot use this method. Please use `getSystemService()` to retrieve a `WindowManager`, as is described in [the `WindowManager` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html).

Answer (score 123):

Simple code you only need context

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

More info go to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

Or you can use this one

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
```

but read documentation

> Return the current display metrics that are in effect for this
>   resource object. The returned object should be treated as **read-only**.